# Error - [Deprecation] Synchronous when making a jQuery AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am getting the following error when trying to use jQuery. I couldn't find the solution.

> jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

The file path is correct and everything. I also installed the latest version of jQuery and correctly called it in the script tag as `src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"`

Main HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- Boxicons CDN Link -->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="">testing
    <div include-html="./ToDoApp/index.html" id="todo-app"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="include-html.min.js"></script>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Custom jQuery function to add HTML file in another HTML file:

```js
$(function() {
  $("*[include-html]").each(function() {
    var t = $(this).attr("include-html"),
      u = this.id;
      
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: t,
      success: function(t) {
        $("#" + u).html(t)
      },
      error: function(n, c, i) {
        var s = n.status + ": " + n.statusText;
        $("#" + u).html(t + "-" + s)
      }
    })
  })
});
```

HTML file to insert in main index file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>dashboard</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- Boxicons CDN Link -->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" id="todo-app">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="clear">
        <i class="bx bx-refresh"></i>
      </div>
      <div id="date"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="items-content">
        <ul class="list" id="list">
          <div>testing</div>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="add-item">
        <i class="bx bxs-plus-circle"></i>
        <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add a to-do">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code you've shown will not cause the synchronous AJAX error.

Comment: That said, there are some issues in your code. The URL you call will need to be changed as `./` doesn't work in HTML/JS. Make the path relative to the root of the domain, eg. `/Todoapp/...`. I would also suggest you change the non-standard HTML attributes to data attributes to avoid issues with non-standard attributes, use `data-include-html="./ToDoApp/index.html"` instead. Also, don't include the entire HTML page within another, as the `html`, `head``, body` etc elements will be ignored. Just retrieve the HTML you actually need to display.

Comment: I see but why is the warning showing? Also, my html page that I am inserting in another html file isnt formating correctly.

Comment: I see. Or is there a better way to insert an html file within another html file than the code that I have?

Comment: Sure, place all the `<link />` and `<script />` tags in the *first* page, ie. the one that makes the AJAX request. This is because the styling and JS needs to be applied to the dynamic content as it's added to the parent page. Also remove anything outside of the `#todo-app` div in the content you load, as it's not necessary at all. If you're having issues with this I'd suggest you research an AJAX tutorial, as this will all be covered in detail there.

Comment: Okay yeah it was the css file. It displays it the way I want it now. Awesome. But the warning is still there. Should I ignore it?

Comment: I am getting the following error as I try to use the script file ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')```

Comment: nvm I resolved. Thanks for your help